# Why return with parentheses in the same line works but parentheses in a new line does not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why in javascript a return with parentheses at the same line works but return undefined when parentheses is at a new line ?

this one works

```
addOne = (i) => {
  return (
    i + 1
  );
}
```

but this one return undefined

```
addOne = (i) => {
  return 
  (
    i + 1
  );
}
```

Comment: It's plain Javascript problem. The return statement will be affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). You could refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return.

Comment: it is because javascript auto insert a semicolon after the return